# Unable to assign value from then callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a Future value and assign it to a bool. I cannot use async/await.
This is my code, but `value` just prints null. `futureFunction` returns `Future<bool>`

```
bool value;
futureFunction().then((a) { value = a; } );
print(value);
```

Comment: does futureFunction returns bool ?

Comment: futureFunction returns Future<bool> @KrishBhanushali

Answer (score 0):

if you put it inside StatefulWidget, this should work

```
bool value;

_StatefulWidgetDemoState() {
  futureFunction().then(
    (returnedValue) => setState(() {
      value = returnedValue;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this already, but doesn't seem to work... probably this code is in a State<> and not a StatefeulWidget IDK. But it does repeatedly print something in the console, so not a good sign

Answer (score 0):

`then` will not wait to finish any task. After completing the future function, code inside `then` will execute. Instate of using `then` use `await` keyword and don't forget to make the function async.
Example:

```
getBool() async{
 bool value = await futureFunction();
 print(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned that I cannot async//await. I need a solution without it

Comment: can you tell me the use of that bool value? Do you want to update the UI or something else?

Comment: The return value is used in a conditional operator to generate a widget. Basically (boolReturn?widget1:widget2)

Comment: then you should use FutureBuilder